# How do I pass reference by value here

Tags: javascript

```
var numCorrect = 0;
var numWrong = 0;

function checkAnswer(numCorrect,numWrong){

var userAns = document.getElementById('ans').value;

if (userAns == x) {
numCorrect++;
}
else {
numWrong++;
console.log("wrong");
}
return numCorrect, numWrong;

}
```

How do i use pass by value here to increment this number by one instead of the variable reseting itself to its initial value after each run?
I initialized to both to zero but it adds 1 to either value and resets to 0

Comment: Calling `incrementFoo` does *not* reset `foo` to its initial value. Either provide a better description of your problem or an example that actually demonstrates your problem. As it is, I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

Primitives are always passed by value. Workaround would be to wrap it in an object.

```
var foo =  { value: 0 }
function increment(wrapper) {
  wrapper.value++
}
increment(foo)
// foo.value here is incremented
```